# How to save one plot for each variable contained in a matrix as a R element and with the variable name as element name? (With a loop)

Tags: r, function, loops, plot, ggplot2

I've tried this

`fdist <- function(X) {
  for(i in 1:ncol(X)){
    print(i)
    gg <- ggplot(X, aes(x=X[,i])) + stat_ecdf(geom = "step")
    gg <- gg + labs(x=paste(names(X[,i])))
    assign(paste(names(X[,i]), i, sep = ''), gg + labs(x = names(X[,i])))
  end} 
}`

but at first I got all plots saved with the numeration as names, and now isn't even getting to save the plots as R elements.

Thanks for help.

Comment: How about saving the plots into a list and the using `setNames`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use a data frame. `ggplot2` works much better with data frames.

```
df = as.data.frame(X)
```

Better to create your plots in a named list than as many separate objects. The creation can be simple using `lapply` like this:

```
plot_list = lapply(names(df), function(x) {
  ggplot(df[x], aes_string(x = x)) +
    stat_ecdf(geom = "step") 
})
```

Looping/`lapply`ing over the names means the default label will be correct. And use `aes_string()` instead of `aes()` when using a column name stored in a variable.

If you arent comfortable with `lapply` you can still use a `for` loop for the same result:

```
plot_list = list()
for (x in names(df)) {
  plot_list[[x]] = ggplot(df[x], aes_string(x = x)) +
    stat_ecdf(geom = "step") 
}
```